# How to create a project for Xamarin.Forms with .NET Standard (VS2017)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

I tried both the `.NET Standard` and the `Class Library (Xamarin.Forms)` projects and didn't get any project for iOS and Android. I then tried `Cross Platform App (Xamarin)` and had to manually change the target to .NET Standard, which forced me to first remove the original NuGet packages. And now the project is littered with red squiggly lines.

So how do I create a Xamarin.Forms project targeting .NET Standard, for iOS and Android (and UWP)?

Comment: Before Xamarin publishes an official project template, you might do that manually. All details can be found in Oren's post, https://oren.codes/2017/04/23/using-xamarin-forms-with-net-standard-vs-2017-edition/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, you'll need to do it manually as you described above, because there is no template available.

The current release of Xamarin.Forms, v2.3.4, doesn't support NET Standard. However, Xamarin.Forms v2.3.5 *does* support NET Standard, and it is currently [available on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/2.3.5.239-pre3) as a pre-release.

After manually converting your PCL to NET Standard, add Xamarin.Forms v2.3.5 to it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm accepting this as the semi-official answer. When are you expected to **release** v2.3.5 and add a template to Visual Studio for NET standard for Xamarin.Forms? Any ETA?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a template for that at the moment.

If you want to put all the platform independent code into the NetStandard project create one using Cross Platform App (Xamarin) - then select Xamarin.Forms and Portable Class Library (PCL)

Then delete the PCL and (from the solution and the folder) and add a netstandard library in it's place (and reference it in the platform projects)

I'm always using the 'Shared Project' approach and adding everything non Xamarin.Forms (like ViewModels) in a separate PCL / netstandard library.